# How can I debug kendoUi for some problems in multiselctors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I need to debug kendo.all.js because I have problem with multiselectors when I select three or more item and remove one of selected items all other items will remove except the first Item.

I have tried putting some breakpoint in the kendo js file, when other kendo components like kendowindow launch it will reach but for this multiselector it will never reach.
Can pls someone help why this happen?

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/say-hello-to-the-kendo-ui-chrome-inspector)

Comment: Thanks , That was Generally helpful.